# SQL model clause - execute rules for only one instance of chosen dimension

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I use SQL model clause to get some data from the database. I have a dimension which value is the same for multiple rows (which is ok and it should happen).

I also have a reference model dimensioned by chosen main dimension. I would like to get values from reference model only for the first row of results.

An example to explaint it better:

Actual results:

```
MAIN DIMENSION | Field 1 | Reference Model Field | Other fields...
    2013-01-01 |     100 |                     1 | Other values...
    2013-01-01 |     100 |                     1 | Other values...
    2013-01-01 |     100 |                     1 | Other values...
    2013-01-01 |     100 |                     1 | Other values...
```

What I would like to receive:

```
MAIN DIMENSION | Field 1 | Reference Model Field | Other fields...
    2013-01-01 |     100 |                     1 | Other values...
    2013-01-01 |     100 |                0/null | Other values...
    2013-01-01 |     100 |                0/null | Other values...
    2013-01-01 |     100 |                0/null | Other values...
```

I have 3 dimensions in main model, 1 in reference model and in rules section I have:

```
ref_model_field[any, any, any] = REFERENCE.field[cv(main_dimension)]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've managed to find a solution. It was pretty easy when I remembered that when you use `partition by` in model clause, rules are calculated for every partitioned instance. So I added another dimension to main model defined as:

```
row_number() over (partition by main_dimension order by some_other_field)
```

In rule definition I only had to calculate value for first numbered row in new dimension:

```
ref_model_field[any, any, any, 1] = REFERENCE.field[cv(main_dimension)]
```

And that's enough to get only one value for multiple rows with the same dimension value.